# Single Push Without Github Action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github repository for which I have an CI script set up using Github Actions. On 95% of the pushes into main, we need to run the script, so the script is triggered by `push` on `main`. Is there a way to push *without* executing actions as an exception. I am imagining something like:

```
git push main --no-action
```

Comment: GitHub actions are controlled by GitHub, which is not the same a git. git commands are only local to the machine running them. For instance `--no-verify` will skip pre-add/add/push checks.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the distinction between GitHub and git in general. But I thought that GitHub uses their own fork of git with a few small changes. Plus all platforms have CI/CD these days, don’t they? Sad too hear that commands are only local.

Comment: What do you mean? GitHub is a git repo hosting platform, not a fork of git?

Comment: GitHub does modify git, but they contribute their changes back – see, for example, [here](https://github.blog/2021-04-29-scaling-monorepo-maintenance/).

Comment: What is specific about these changes where the workflow shouldn't be triggered? Maybe there's a way via branch/tag/path filters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have GitHub Actions skip a push event by including `[skip ci]` or any of the variants of that in your commit message as described in the [GitHub Actions docs on skipping workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs).